# Return time for two independent one dimensional random walks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $X^1$ and $X^{-1}$ be two simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ starting respectively from $1$ and $-1$. Let $\tau$ be the first time one of them reaches the origin,

$$\tau = \inf \{ j \geq 0 \, : \, X^{-1}(j) = 0 \, \, \mbox{or}\, \,  X^{1}(j) = 0 \}.$$

How much is $E[\tau]$, the expectation of $\tau$?

**Comment:** If there was only a random walk, then the expectation of $\tau$ would be infinite, as $P(\tau >k ) \sim 1/k$. However, for two random walks I think it should not be infinite, as $P(\tau >k ) \sim 1/k^2$. How to make it rigorous and compute the exact number?

Comment: I think you just need to note that $\tau$ is the minimum of the the two stopping times related to the two random walks ($\tau_1$ and $\tau_{-1}$, say). Therefore $P(\tau>k)=P(\tau_1>k) P(\tau_{-1}>k)$. Try to see if this gets you to an explicit form of the expectation.

Comment: Yes. What I need is an explicit formula for 
$$
P(\tau_1 > k)
$$

Comment: Actually, $P(\tau_1>k)\sim1/\sqrt{\pi k}$ hence $E(\tau)$ is infinite.

Comment: Ahhhhhh thanks!! So, I need three walks then!